# Mysql regexp to get right table names from database schema

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to select, from mysql, some specific tables that matches a pattern.

The specific pattern I'm looking for is like '`my_table_number`'. For example, `my_table_436814` or `my_table_35413`. The thing is that there are other tables that looks like `my_table_old_14353` or `my_table_351434_times`. I just want to filter out the ones that are `my_table_number`.

I have tried different patterns, but failed to get what I really need.

The most closest approach was with this:

```
select table_name from 
information_schema.columns ca 
where ca.table_name REGEXP '[0-9]$'
```

How can I achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Is `my_table`  a fixed string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes

Comment: Ok, then the answer below is doing what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```sql
REGEXP '^my_table_[0-9]+$'
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/QacB7T/1)

| NODE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `my_table_` | 'my_table_' |
| `[0-9]+` | any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `$` | before an optional \n, and the end of the string |

Comment: This actually solved the problem. Thank you, very much! One las thing, this works with and without the `^` symbol. Why?

Comment: @xerac If you do not want to ensure the match happens to be at the beginning of the string, you do not need `^`.